# Repository save killing performance CPU utilisation

Tags: multithreading, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my spring boot application, I have a ThreadPoolExecutor with 100 fixed threads. I have configured datasource as:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() throws IOException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dbDatasource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.pkg"});
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("dbEntityManager");
        HibernatePersistenceProvider hibernatePersistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
        em.setPersistenceProvider( hibernatePersistenceProvider );
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.naming-strategy", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("jdbc.show-sql"));
        properties.put("logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL", env.getProperty("logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL"));
        properties.put("logging.level.org.hibernate.type", env.getProperty("logging.level.org.hibernate.type"));

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dbDatasource() throws IOException {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        System.out.println("DATABASE:" + dataSource.getUrl() +" "+ dataSource.getUsername());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException{
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

repository.save(entity) (of JpaRepository) is one of the operations that happens in the thread. The first save takes about 222ms but as there is load I see time taken to save rises 50-100ms per request reaching upto 10seconds per save.

Also, my CPU utilization shoots up incredibly to about 90%.

Can someone please help understand what I am missing?

Comment: Did you tried setup JDBC Connection pooling? For example https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0?

Comment: @Tijkijiki I thought of adding a pool but even after reading a lot I dont know which one is better- Hikari/BoneCP/DBCP. Moreover if I am observing 100+ writes per second then what should be my maxActiveConnections.

Comment: Moreover we have other projects which use similar configuration and they easily scale upto 400tps. But they have mysql RDS